# CentOS 7 install pecl/pear ius

Tags: php, centos, centos7, pear, pecl

How do I install pecl/pear on CentOS 7 with PHP 7.2 installed via the IUS repo?

Currently installed is `php72u`.

I've tried installing `php-pear` but it results in a PHP error when running pecl:

```php
# pecl
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Frontend.php on line 91
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IUS provides the pecl/pear binaries via the package `pear1`, unlike other repos which use `php-pear`.

```sh
yum install pear
pecl
```